# Unix sed XML config editing

Tags: linux, sed

I have a little problem with sed .

I want to edit an XML-based config file with sed. Within Putty, the command is working but when I used the same command in a Bash script, nothing happens.

```
sed -i ./mods/deathmatch/mtaserver.conf -e \
  's#<serverip>\([^<][^<]*\)</serverip>#<serverip>'`echo $IP`'</serverip>#'
```

Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: Don't use backticks (**`**); use `$(echo "$IP")` or use double quotes around the whole sed command and just `$IP` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Use an XML processing tool for parsing XML, such as [xmlstarlet](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/overview.php)

```
$ cat config.xml 
<config><server>something</server></config>
$ xmlstarlet ed -L -O -P -u //server -v new_value config.xml
$ cat config.xml 
<config><server>new_value</server></config>
```

Comment: xmlstarlet working thx, but i had to solve it with sed instead

Answer (score 0):

Not to go all 'Clippy' on you, but it looks like you're trying to point your config at a server that changes IP from time to time.

You might consider creating a local name in your `/etc/hosts` file and leave your configurations static.

Supposing your deathmatch server IP is `10.10.10.1`:

```
# in your /etc/hosts:
10.10.10.1   deathmatch
```

Then in your `mtaserver.conf` you would just have it reference `deathmatch` (or whatever name you like) instead of an IP address.  Your machine should resolve `deathmatch` to your server IP address.

Depending on how names are resolved on your machine, this should just work.  If you look at `/etc/nsswitch.conf` you should see a line that declares `files` before `dns`

```
vagrant@precise32:~$ grep '^hosts' /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:          files dns
```

If you see this, you should be OK to manage the IP in `/etc/hosts`.